# How to change protocol of schemaLocation in Metro web service

Tags: web-services, service, web, wsdl, java-metro-framework

I have a web service deployed behind firewall.
Connection between firewall and WS is on 8080 port, but firewall accept requests from outside only on 443 port.

The problem is that when I open wsdl from outside, **schemaLocation** attribute has wrong value - begins with **http://host:8080**, but not with **https://host:443**

I can change port as described here:
http://metro.java.net/2.0/guide/HTTP_address_in_soap_address_and_import_locations.html
but it lead to wrong: **http://host:443** 
Does anyone know how to fix ***protocol*** of **schemaLocation** attribute from **http** to **https**?

Answer (score 0):

it is here: [new location of metro user guide](https://javaee.github.io/metro/doc/user-guide/ch05.html#http-address-in-soapaddress-and-import-locations)